# Как работают Read и Write в консольном режиме в Lazarus?

Tags: lazarus

При работе на Lazarus есть консольный режим, который во вкладке Проект открывается как Программа пользователя. Это, конечно, очень здорово, можно писать, как на Паскале. Вот только помогите, пожалуйста, где в этом режиме работают команды ввода - вывода, любимые Read и Write, куда они выдают? На экране ничего не отображается, в окне Сообщения тоже, окна Формы в этом режиме нет. В каком окне результат работы программы-то посмотреть? Может, что еще открыть надо?

Comment: @Наталья Павловна Храмова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Файл->Создать... В списке выбираете "Консольное приложение". В появившемся окошке жмете ок. В редакторе кода вписывает свой код там, где написано `{ add your program here }`, или как вариант стираете все и пишете с нуля "как на Паскале".

В конце программы (перед `end.`) поставьте `readln;`, чтобы окошко консоли не закрылось сразу после вывода.